# How to use Page Ids retrieved from Database in the HMenu?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm currently working on my first typo project and need to create a mega menu with an individual set of pages.

Many attempts failed or are not suitable for me. My current shot aims to group pages of the redirect type in a hidden page. In Typoscript I want to set the ID of the parent page containing these redirections and read the shortcut IDs of the children accordingly.

```
pageIds = CONTENT
pageIds {
  table = pages
  select {
    selectFields = shortcut
    pidInList = 614 # Id of the container Page
  }
}
```

The next step would be to use the retrieved shortcut IDs in my HMENU of the type 'list'.

```
1 = HMENU
1 {
  special = list
  special {
    value = # Assign retrieved IDs here
  }
  [...]
}
```

Typoscript is very confusing at first sight, so I would be glad to receive some hints how I can transfer the query's result, as a comma-seperated list, to the HMENU.

Thanks in advance!
Greetz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to get a comma-separated list of the page UIDs you want to link. This can be achieved with a renderObj:

```
lib.pageIds = CONTENT
lib.pageIds {
  table = pages
  select {
    selectFields = shortcut
    pidInList = 614 # Id of the container Page
  }
  renderObj = TEXT
  renderObj.stdWrap.field = shortcut
  renderObj.stdWrap.wrap = |,
}
```

This should give you a comma-separated list of all records. Now you must apply these to the HMENU. As you can read in the documentation, the `value` property is stdWrap enabled, this means that you can copy a value when you use a `cObject`:

```
1 = HMENU
1 {
  special = list
  special {
    value.cObject < lib.pageIds
  }
  [...]
}
```

*I didn't test this, so maybe the configuration is not entirely complete.*

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried out many combinations of what you answered but never achieved what i aimed for. I think I missed the .cObject at the special.value assignment.

Comment: I don't understand: Does it work now? If you needed to make adjustments, please edit my answer so the next user finds a working example.

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I did not express myself very well. I tried different approaches similiar to yours, before you posted your answer. Your code snippet was working on the first shot. Thanks again.